# Plotting two graphs getting the error: Cannot convert object of class list into a grob

Tags: r, plot, cowplot

I am trying to place two boxplots (box1, box2) beside each other and to label them "A" and "B" in the upper left corner. I am trying to use the `cowplot`-package for this.

This is the function:

```
plot_grid(box1, box2, labels = c('A', 'B'), label_size = 12)
```

Then I get the warning message:

> In as_grob.default(plot) :
> Cannot convert object of class list into a grob.*

And the only printout I get is the A and B letters.
I have also tried to use:

```
boxC <- c(box1, bow2)
plot_grid(plotlist = boxC, labels = c('A', 'B'), label_size = 12, nrow=2)
```

My code mostly came from the answers to this similar question, but it does not seem to work for me.

[Lay out multiple ggplot graphs on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58124284/lay-out-multiple-ggplot-graphs-on-a-page)

In that question someone also suggested using `dev.off()` but that did not work for me either.

So grateful for replies!

The solution that I wrote based on mhh's reply:

```
BOX1_data <- read.table(file = "clipboard", 
                  sep = "\t", header=TRUE)
BOX1_data$Histology <- as.factor(BOX1_data$Histology)
BOX1plot <- ggplot(BOX1_data, aes(x=Histology, y=No.Variants)) + geom_boxplot()
BOX1plot

BOX2_data <- read.table(file = "clipboard", 
                  sep = "\t", header=TRUE)
BOX2_data$Stage <- as.factor(BOX2_data$Stage)
BOX2plot <- ggplot(BOX2_data, aes(x=Stage, y=No.Variants)) + geom_boxplot()
BOX2plot

BOX_list <- list(BOX1plot, BOX2plot)
> ggarrange(plotlist = BOX_list, labels = c('A', 'B'), ncol = 2)
```

Comment: Your main issue is that your plot list is not a list! Try with `boxC <- list(box1,box2)` and you will see that it works perfectly.

Comment: I tried this by writing: 
> boxC <- list(box1,bow2)
> plot_grid(plotlist = boxC, labels = c('A', 'B'), label_size = 12, nrow=2)
But the same error occurs.

Comment: Try to not include `label_size = 12`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because it is expecting a list, but you are providing a vector!
To overcome this, you can simply use `boxC <- list(box1,box2)`.

Here is a working example

To do this, you need `ggplot2` and `ggpubr`
Install the latter with `install.packages("ggpubr")`.
Then get them both into your workspace with `library(ggpubr)`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
df1 <- data.frame(group = "Stuff",  var = runif(10))
df2 <- data.frame(group = "Stash",  var = runif(10))

box1 <- ggplot(data = df1, aes(y = var)) +
  geom_boxplot()

box2 <- ggplot(data = df2, aes(y = var)) +
  geom_boxplot()

my_plot_list <- list(box1,box2)

ggarrange(plotlist = my_plot_list, labels = c('A', 'B'), nrow = 2)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-08-19 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: I tried applying your code mhh like this:
dfbox1 <- data.frame(group = box_data)
> dfbox2 <- data.frame(group = box2_data)
> box1df <- ggplot(data = dfbox1, aes(y = var)) +
+     geom_boxplot()
> box2df <- ggplot(data = dfbox2, aes(y = var)) +
+     geom_boxplot()
> box_list <- list(box1df,box2df)
> ggarrange(plotlist = box_list, labels = c('A', 'B'), nrow = 2)
But then I get this error: 
Error: Aesthetics must be valid data columns. Problematic aesthetic(s): y = var. 
Did you mistype the name of a data column or forget to add after_stat()?

Comment: Is this because I did not specify the "var="? I am very new to this so what should I put instead of your random 10 numbers?

Comment: Can you include the code for your plots in your original question, @Alvida?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to mhh's answer I made this code which works! :)

```
BOX1_data <- read.table(file = "clipboard", 
                  sep = "\t", header=TRUE)
BOX1_data$Histology <- as.factor(BOX1_data$Histology)
BOX1plot <- ggplot(BOX1_data, aes(x=Histology, y=No.Variants)) + geom_boxplot()
BOX1plot

BOX2_data <- read.table(file = "clipboard", 
                  sep = "\t", header=TRUE)
BOX2_data$Stage <- as.factor(BOX2_data$Stage)
BOX2plot <- ggplot(BOX2_data, aes(x=Stage, y=No.Variants)) + geom_boxplot()
BOX2plot

BOX_list <- list(BOX1plot, BOX2plot)
> ggarrange(plotlist = BOX_list, labels = c('A', 'B'), ncol = 2)
```

Comment: If my answer (or yours) has the appropriate answer for the question, please mark it as the accepted answer so that others may more easily find the solution. In this case, my perhaps biased opinion would lean towards my answer, as it provides example data and visual output. :)

Comment: Absolutely! This was my first question on the forum so I am not so familiar with it yet. Thank you for the help!